# C# 5 ReportExecutionService

Tags: c#, reporting-services, breakpoints, ssrs-2017, ssis-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and C# 7.3 to execute data driven SSRS 2017 report execution.

Visual Studio 2017 requires using C#5 for break points to function properly. I can change to C#5, but I can I can find no documentation on C#5 and ReportExecutionService. The following is C# 7.3. It runs great but I can't debug my code to get rid of some minor annoyances in the SSIS package.

```
`result = rexec.Render(format, devInfo, out string extension, out string 
    mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIDs);`
```

For more on Visual Studio and trouble with break points visit:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/185808/could-not-set-breakpoint-in-ssis-scripttask.html

Comment: "Visual Studio 2017 requires using C#5 for break points to function properly" [citation needed]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I amended the post. I guess I thought that this is such a widely known issue that it would be obvious. I won't forget the lesson.

Comment: Seems that this is only something that Microsoft can fix. :(

Comment: I totally agree. It is my hope that someone will be able to give me the parameters I need to use for ReportExecutionService.Render in C#5. That may be a pipe dream.